# On Yau's (and Schoen's) proof of the positive mass theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, minimal-surfaces

I would like to face the proof of the positive mass theorem by Yau and Schoen. I have a Bsc in Mathematics and a Msc in Theoretical Physics and I'm preparing a PhD interview-challenge where I have to explain as better as I can the proof by these two authors of the positive mass theorem. Since it's pretty complicated and I have to cover my initial background, I would like to know if there exists some interesting and inspiring surveys about this topic (I found a lot of material on the internet, but it is not deep enough). 
Do you also have a general idea about what one should know to face this topic? Any books you can suggest? I read all their works about and the amount of technicalities risks to loose myself!

Thanks a lot for your attention!

Bye,
Mattia

Comment: This may be helpful: a survey written by Hugh Bray (a former student of Schoen). This article seems to have appeared in a book dedicated to Schoen's 60th birthday, which might have other useful articles for you.
http://arxiv.org/abs/1101.2230v1